# IOS 13 Sprite Kit Issues

Tags: sprite-kit, collision-detection, frame-rate, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

I recently made a game using sprite kit xcode 10.2 which was working fine unless ios 13 update, I tested the game in xcode 11 simulators with ios 13 the fps of the game starts to get reduce to 30-35fps. Also, sometimes physics body on sprite nodes is not working properly. [sometimes collision is detected on sprite nodes and sometimes it is being detected in middle of the sprite node which was not the case in ios 12 everything was working fine until ios 13 update.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFUlZ.png)

Comment: ios 13 most likely requires more resources.  Test on hardware before presenting problems in SO, the lag caused by the simulator could be causing a lot of your problems

Comment: I tested the game on iphone 6s it was working fine with no fps drop but after ios 13 update its causing issues and fps are droping to 35-35fps

Comment: ok, well nobody can help you without posting code.  For all we know Apple fixed a bug because you were not doing something properly, and now it is affecting you.

Comment: Are you using a physics body created from a texture? I'm having issues with that in iOS 13, where the body is not the same as in earlier iOS versions.

Comment: Something is definitely broken with textures and physics bodies in iOS 13.  Here's the same game under iOS 12 vs iOS 13: [example](https://i.imgur.com/vsGZLLz.png)

Comment: yes i'm using a physics body created from texture.

Comment: how can i see the physics body created from textures? as in your above example image?

Comment: Set view.showsPhysics = true

Comment: In the viewDidLoad method (in GameViewController.swift if you've used the Xcode game template), you probably set various view flags such as view.showsFPS, view.showsNodeCount.  To see physics bodies view.showsPhysics = true

Comment: 0x141E is a Ninja :-)

Comment: this similar fps drop problem was caused during ios 9 update which was later fixed by apple after ios 9.2 update.. also this broken physics body might get resolved during upcoming updates.

Comment: @bg2b did you file a bug report with Apple regarding the physics body from a texture issue?

Comment: Yes, with the Feedback Assistant, but didn't hear anything. We added some code to switch to a polygon physicsBody based on a convex hull for iOS 13. For our sprites, it's close enough for now.

Comment: yes i had reported the bug but got no response .i'll try adding the polygon physics body. thanks for all your help.

Comment: @bg2b looks like Apple fixed the issue in iOS 13.2

Comment: Good to know, thanks, though I'll have to leave the convex hull workaround in the code for people who don't upgrade.

Comment: Sigh, spoke too soon.  13.2 is failing for me with "PhysicsBody: Could not create physics body."  That's when the sprite is in an atlas.  Outside of the atlas it works, but that's not feasible for us since it blows the number of draws.  Maybe there's some issue with the Xcode 11.2 beta and sprite atlases.  I tried build cleaning and making a new atlas with just the sprites that need conforming bodies, but no luck.

Comment: OK.  If iOS <= 12, normal make body from texture.  If iOS >= 13.0 && iOS < 13.2, make body from convex hull of texture.  If iOS == 13.2, make body from a copy of the texture that's not in an atlas and associate it with the normal texture that is in the atlas.  What should be 3 lines of code is now 18.  Thanks Apple, you've boosted my productivity by a factor of 6!

Comment: well i think it's better to make games on some gaming engine with better physics than apples sprite kit. Apple had just made things worse.

Comment: @bg2b can you post this example as an answer?