# Creating a physics body using a texture's alpha channel not working in Xcode 11.1

Tags: sprite-kit, xcode11

I have a project that uses a sprite's texture to create the physics body. This works in Xcode 10.1. The same code is not working in Xcode 11.1

I opened a project in 11.1 and the physics body is no longer being detected nor is an outline being shown when `view.showPhysics` is set to true for any of the sprites using a texture to define its physics body. It still works fine when specifying a circle or rectangle shape for a physics body.

This is how you set it up... right from the Apple docs.

```swift
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spaceship")
sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: sprite.texture!,
                                   size: sprite.texture!.size())
```

I see no updated info on Apple's site regarding changes in this functionality.

Comment: Physics bodies from textures is currently broken in iOS 13. See, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58062098/ios-13-sprite-kit-issues

Comment: You're right, it works in iOS 12.4, thanks! FWIW, I'm not getting nil back, not a misshapen physics body (like your example link in the comments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per bg2b's response to my question, the solution for now is either go back to iOS 12.4 or wait for Apple to fix iOS 13.1.

Comment: iOS 13.3.1 and still no fix :(. I can’t believe they’ve just so utterly left us dead in the water this long.  I do not want to completely rework the collision detection I’ve got in place on 50+ levels to this extent.  My levels are far too complicated to ever capture that kind of detail without texture based masks.  This has put a complete halt to my project, and caused me to give up on my Apple dev account as that would have been a waste of $99 if I can’t work on my game anymore let alone release it.

Comment: @DiggyJohn Is there a way to extract the generated shapes of the physics bodies while it is running under 12.4, exporting that data, and then apply those as polygons in your code instead of using the texture alpha to create the bodies? Alternatively, finding an algorithm to create polygons from alphas to use.

Comment: those sound like great ideas.  With my current schedule and the small amount of time I get to work on this, however, I'll likely wait till iOS 14 comes out in a few months to see if the issue has been fixed before trying.  I'll get it working, then they'll release the fix, and 99% of the iOS users will be off iOS 13 anyway lol.

Comment: @DiggyJohn Do we know that Apple even knows that this is an issue? I'm seeing the problem but I can't find any release notes about it.

Comment: @JustinNgan, Yes, they are aware of it.  I have a support ticket open with them that they've responded to a few times, and given me some example source code to try as a workaround.  Nothing has worked.  iOS 13.5 came out recently, guess I should go and see if that addressed it.

Comment: @DiggyJohn Awesome!  "Nothing has worked" - Awesome!  Okay, maybe not.  Thanks for sharing the status, we'll wait and see.

Comment: @JustinNgan, FYI, here is the workaround Apple suggested.  The issue seems to be centered around the sks editor itself.  Remove all alpha physic body assignments from the editor.  Then create them manually in code instead.  This did get me further... however, a new completely different bug sprang up for me immediately in that 80% of my nodes in my sks just don't load at all, including my CAMERA lol.  Attempts at getting references to most of my nodes all come back nil, and that's even if I remove all alpha physic bodies from my entire level.  I reported this one too.

Comment: @DiggyJohn This is crazy that Apple is getting you to try different approaches like this. Do they know that it works in prior versions of Xcode? If it worked previously and doesn't after a build, do they not see it as a problem with their release ? !  I mean, they don't expect everyone to change their code constantly ?

Comment: @JustinNgan they do see it as a problem and have said that have identified the issue and a fix is coming in a future release of iOS... of course, numerous minor versions have been released since then, none of which contained a fix for these issues.

Comment: @JustinNgan In my experience, yes, they expect everyone to change their code constantly.  Just look at the evolution of Swift.  The deprecation of OpenGL.  Requiring Swift apps to the latest version or you can't even build.  Requiring apps be released on the latest SDK, which only works in the latest Xcode, which only works on the latest OS, which stops working on older Macs.  I have code from 2007 for WIndows based projects that I can compile and run now.  None of my iOS projects from 2018 will even compile without major overhauls.  I have many millions of lines of OpenGL code out the window.

Comment: They finally fixed this in iOS 14.  Too bad I lost an entire year of development time due to this nonsense.  Apple updated my feedback assistant ticket saying “potential fix in iOS 14” and asked me to test, and send logs if it still didn’t address the issue.  This tells me support was never actively communicating this issue with the devs.  Support just kept kicking my ticket down the road each new version released “hoping” each time a dev addressed it, asking me each time “is it fixed yet?” same as me.  Feedback assistant is an illusion, not a bug tracking system anyone is paying attention to.

Comment: @DiggyJohn I think what you state definitely brings frustration. I only want to offer a potential rationale: By doing what you describe, Apple is able to ensure a common experience for all apple users of all their supported computers.  I know that's entirely true, Apple hides a lot of new features from older devices without very good reasons or any reasons. Many seem to look like ways of encouraging users to upgrade hardware. The OpenGL issue is clearly one of the worst. That said, I expect that it is tied to their moving to the Apple silicon. You have to admit, they timed that intentionally.