# How to check if two sprite nodes' textures intersect

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm creating a simple game (similar to the Google Chrome T-Rex game) where the user has to jump over barrels. The issue I'm coming across is that the user is losing because the frames of the two nodes intersect. However, the textures that I'm using don't take up the whole frame, so it looks like a bug. Is there any way that I can check if the *textures* themselves collide instead of the frames?

[image]

Here's the code that I'm using to create the character node

```
    private lazy var avatarNode: SKSpriteNode = {
        let node = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "fox")
        node.name = "avatar"
        let width: CGFloat = 85
        let height: CGFloat = width * (437.0 / 360.0) // This is the aspect ratio of the texture
        node.size = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
        node.position = CGPoint(x: width / 2 + 50, y: Constants.groundHeight + height / 2)
        node.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: node.size)
        node.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true // 2
        node.physicsBody?.mass = 1.0
        node.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        node.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
        node.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
        node.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = GameCategories.avatar
        node.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = GameCategories.ground
        node.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = GameCategories.barrel
        return node
    }()
```

And here's how I'm creating the barrel node:

```
        let barrelHeight: CGFloat = 50
        let barrelWidth: CGFloat = rockHeight * CGFloat(192.0 / 237.0)
        let barrelNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "game-barrel")
        barrelNode.name = "barrel"
        barrelNode.size = CGSize(width: barrelWidth, height: barrelHeight)
        barrelNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width + barrelWidth / 2, y: Constants.groundHeight + barrelHeight / 2)
        barrelNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: barrelNode.size)
        barrelNode.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
        barrelNode.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        barrelNode.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        barrelNode.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
        barrelNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = GameCategories.barrel
        barrelNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
        barrelNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = GameCategories.avatar
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a physics body using a texture's alpha channel not working in Xcode 11.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58544851/creating-a-physics-body-using-a-textures-alpha-channel-not-working-in-xcode-11)

Answer (score 0):

There is an initializer: [`SKPhysicsBody(texture:size:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1519690-init).

So initializing the physics body like this worked:

```
 barrelNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "game-barrel"),
                                        size: barrelNode.size)
```