# Issues with SKPhysicsBody from Texture

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I have searched around the internet / StackOverflow for the past few days without much success in finding an answer to a few questions that I believe are intertwined in some way.

1. How do I prevent my game from freezing when it is rendering an SKPhysicsBody from a texture?
2. Why are my physics bodies sometimes not created at all, and why are they sometimes the wrong shapes?

Below is the code I am using to try and generate these pillars (image attached at the bottom of the post. There are roughly 6-8 at any point in time before they are removed. When I change the shape to just a rectangle, I get no lag / freezing at all and the physics object is created properly every time.

Is this SKPhysicsBody rendering too complex, or is there a way that I can have my game run smoothly while still generating a correctly shaped physics object? Below is the function I use to set up the walls as they are created in my game.

func createWalls() {

```
    let scoreNode = SKSpriteNode()

    wallPair = SKNode()
    wallPair.name = "wallPair"

    //MARK: - Top Wall Setup
    let topWall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Pillar")
    topWall.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 700)
    topWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: topWall.texture!, size: topWall.size)
    topWall.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.maxX+50, y: 0 + 400)
    topWall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Wall
    topWall.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Character
    topWall.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Character
    topWall.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    topWall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    topWall.zRotation = .pi



    //MARK: - Bot Wall Setup
    let botWall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Pillar")
    botWall.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 700)
    botWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: botWall.texture!, size: botWall.size)
    botWall.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.maxX+50, y: 0 - 400)
    botWall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Wall
    botWall.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Character
    botWall.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Character
    botWall.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    botWall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false


    scoreNode.size = CGSize(width: 1, height: 600)
    scoreNode.position = CGPoint(x: topWall.position.x+15, y: 0)
    scoreNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: scoreNode.size)
    scoreNode.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    scoreNode.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    scoreNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Score
    scoreNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    scoreNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Character
    scoreNode.color = SKColor.blue

    wallPair.addChild(topWall)
    wallPair.addChild(botWall)
    wallPair.zPosition = 1

    let randomPosition = CGFloat.random(min: -200, max: 200)
    wallPair.position.y = wallPair.position.y + randomPosition
    wallPair.addChild(scoreNode)
    wallPair.run(moveAndRemove)
    self.addChild(wallPair)
```

}

[image: Pillar Image]

Comment: Related to this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58062098/ios-13-sprite-kit-issues#comment103555617_58062098  We haven't had problems with iOS 13.3 and physics bodies from textures as long as the textures aren't in an atlas.  Using textures in an atlas is still broken I believe.  Regardless, I haven't tried to make physics bodies from such large textures. Maybe make one at the start of your game during setup, then `body.copy() as! SKPhysicsBody` will make a copy of the body, though it's not really documented.  Worst case, for a simple shape, making polygons by hand isn't too bad.

Comment: @bg2b Thank you! This worked for me. The game is running smoothly / properly now. I think running the SKPhysicsBody from texture repeatedly on such a large image was too intensive.

Comment: @bg2b, I do not have this issue. i.stack.imgur.com/CfJyW.png
I added Frodgers image to my atlas.... still no problem i.stack.imgur.com/mlQZ8.png
... ok, I tested on different devices I am getting errors now.  It is definelty dependant on device.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I'm not sure what is the root cause of the breakage, but it's definitely affected a lot of others (as well as me). I even see problems in Xcode when doing a quick look at some textures; the previews have odd effects, and the cgImage method sometimes gives screwy results that match what Xcode shows me. Our textures aren't big enough for a few non-atlas duplicates to be worth worrying about fortunately.

Comment: @bg2b I normally use https://www.codeandweb.com/physicseditor and make CGPaths of my bodies.  This allows me to fine tune the polygon, since the less lines the better.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I'll keep that one in mind. I was at one point pretty frustrated and very tempted to just make the paths on my own.

Comment: @bg2b are you using the old method for loading atlases?  When I load the old way, I get the weird screen tears you have across all devices

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I'm not sure since I didn't know there was an old way. I just drag everything into a sprite atlas folder in Assets.xcassets in Xcode and then call SKTexture(imageNamed: ...) for whatever is needed.  I don't do anything explicit to load the atlas at all. (I do know that the sprites are packed into one big image, because I get broken results if I write a shader and forget to account for textureRect).

Comment: Ok, the old way is a folder with an extension of .atlas outside of xcassets

Comment: @bg2b I was wondering if you might know why sometimes when I get to body.copy as! SKPhysicsBody my app crashes and says it can't be cast to that type? It seems to mainly happen when I run a new build and am testing it for the first time on the various simulators.

Comment: @Frodgers I'd have to take a look under a debugger to try to figure out what the problem is.  Obviously it thinks whatever it's got is not a valid physics body, but whether it's because it didn't make one correctly at the start or whether the variable got corrupted somewhere or ??? is not clear.  Worst case, you might have to just trace out a path-based physics body by hand or perhaps using something like the tool mentioned above.  If it seems to copy correctly for a few times and then crash, maybe you can catch it when it does the copy the first time and set a watch point on body.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this extension:

```
extension SKTexture{
  func pristineCopy() -> SKTexture{
      return SKTexture(cgImage:self.cgImage)
  }
}
```

This should temporarily create a new texture for your physics body to use without getting bogged down by the atlas.

Once the `SKPhysicsBody` creates the `CGPath` out of this texture, the memory should get released, so try not to retain it with a variable.

example:

```
func createWalls()
    let scoreNode = SKSpriteNode()

    wallPair = SKNode()
    wallPair.name = "wallPair"

    //MARK: - Top Wall Setup
    let topWall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Pillar")
    topWall.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 700)
    topWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: topWall.texture!.pristineCopy(), size: topWall.size)
    topWall.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.maxX+50, y: 0 + 400)
    topWall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Wall
    topWall.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Character
    topWall.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Character
    topWall.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    topWall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    topWall.zRotation = .pi



    //MARK: - Bot Wall Setup
    let botWall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Pillar")
    botWall.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 700)
    botWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: botWall.texture!.pristineCopy(), size: botWall.size)
    botWall.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.maxX+50, y: 0 - 400)
    botWall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Wall
    botWall.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Character
    botWall.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Character
    botWall.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    botWall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false


    scoreNode.size = CGSize(width: 1, height: 600)
    scoreNode.position = CGPoint(x: topWall.position.x+15, y: 0)
    scoreNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: scoreNode.size)
    scoreNode.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    scoreNode.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    scoreNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Score
    scoreNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    scoreNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Character
    scoreNode.color = SKColor.blue

    wallPair.addChild(topWall)
    wallPair.addChild(botWall)
    wallPair.zPosition = 1

    let randomPosition = CGFloat.random(min: -200, max: 200)
    wallPair.position.y = wallPair.position.y + randomPosition
    wallPair.addChild(scoreNode)
    wallPair.run(moveAndRemove)
    self.addChild(wallPair)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that creating the physics body separately from the node when you're first loading your scene works.

Each time you create a new node, just assign the node the variable containing your preset physics body. Obviously this only works if the sizing of these nodes are always the same

```
var presetPhysicsBody:SKPhysicsBody?

func createPhysicsBody() {
    let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "your-image")
    presetPhysicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: texture, size: CGSize(width: 205, height: 130))
}

spriteNode?.physicsBody = presetPhysicsBody?.copy() as! SKPhysicsBody
spriteNode2?.physicsBody = presetPhysicsBody?.copy() as! SKPhysicsBody
```